# Circular template typename dependency for physics engine

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, polymorphism, circular-dependency

I'm having a lot of trouble converting a polymorphism-based physics engine I wrote to template-based. What I was doing before was having a `SpatialBase` abstract class (spatial paritioning), and a `ResolverBase` abstract class (contact solver). But those two classes were always known at compile-time, so why not templatize the engine and remove the virtual call overheads?

Well, here's the problem:

`template<class TS, class TR> class World;` - this is the `World<TS, TR>` class, `TS` is the spatial partitioning type and `TR` is the contact solver type.

`template<class TS, class TR> class Body;` - this is the `Body<TS, TR>` class. It requires to know both `TS` and `TR` because it stores a `World<TS, TR>&`.

`template<class TR> class Grid;` - this is the `Grid<TR>` class. It requires to know `TR` because it needs to know what `Body<Grid, TR>` is (it stores cells that store bodies).

`template<class TS> class ImpulseSolver;` - this is the `ImpulseSolver<TS>`. It requires to know `TS` because it needs to know what `Body<TS, ImpulseSolver>` is (it directly deals with the body's inner members).

Now... see the issue? It's impossible to declare a correct `World<TS, TR>`!

`World< Grid<ImpulseSolver<Grid<ImpulseSolver..., ImpulseSolver<Grid<ImpulseSolver<Grid... > madWorld; // not by Gary Jules`.

It's a circular dependency. The spatial paritioning class needs to know about the contact solver class and viceversa, because both need to know the exact type of the `Body<TS, TR>` class.

Is there any way to solve this? Or am I doomed to use runtime polymorphism forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `World` to be a template that takes templates as parameters (rather than types). You can then redefine your `Body` and resolving method class templates to be parameterized by `World`.

```
template<class TWORLD> struct Body {
    Body (TWORLD &) {}
    //...
};

template<class TWORLD> struct Grid {
    Grid (Body<TWORLD> &) {}
    //...
};

template<class TWORLD> struct ImpulseSolver {
    ImpulseSolver (Body<TWORLD> &) {}
    //...
};

template <template <typename> class TS,
          template <typename> class TR>
class World {
    Body<World> body_;
    TS<World> spatial_;
    TR<World> resolver_;
public:
    typedef TS<World> SpatialImpl;
    typedef TR<World> ResolverImpl;
    World () : body_(*this), spatial_(body_), resolver_(body_) {}
    //...
};

int main () {
    World<Grid, ImpulseSolver> w;
}
```

Comment: I want the user of my physics engine to decide what spatial partitioning method and what contact solving method to use at compile time.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: You can make `World` be a template that takes template arguments then.

Comment: I don't see how that would help, as I would have to say `ImpulseSolver<World<Grid, ImpulseSolver<...>>>`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: I have updated my answer allowing `World` to take templates as parameters. Please let me know if you still have issues with the approach.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I'll try it out later today and report my results

Answer (score 2):

you can use a [policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to make a class that already uses grid and impulse solver.
then you would use [crtp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to communicate between them.

if you give some simple code i can make a simple example. use meaningful names not TS and TR. use grid_type and solver_type, for example.

I do the same in my science simulation. I make a hamiltonian class that takes an adapter to a coordinates system and an adapter to a method as policies.

**Update (1)**

you might also need to use accurate `using`s but the idea is here:

```
template <class body_type>
struct res_imp {
  body_type& body() {return static_cast<body_type*>(this);}
  void ri(){cout << "howdy, it's ri\n" << body().sgs;}
  string ris;
};

template <class body_type>
struct spa_g {
  body_type& body() {return static_cast<body_type*>(this);}
  void sg() {cout << "yo, it's sg\n" << body().ris;}
  string sgs;
};

template <class res_imp_type, class spa_g_type>
struct body : res_imp_type, spa_g_type {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Body class doesn't need to be a template. You can use pointer instead of reference like `World<TS, TR>*` and forward declare TS and TR in the header of Body.